# Flash canvas tool data migrate to fabric canvas tool data

Tags: flash, canvas, migration, fabricjs

I want to migrate the data of flash tool, which is given in following json file, which have the following syntax in design.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/upeswvqfoyqfvz9/flash%20tool.txt?dl=0

When the same design I have done fabric canvas tool , which have following syntax

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgy5c54mt70uv8p/fabrictool.txt?dl=0

Can any one knows how can I convert the data from flash tool to fabric canvas tool, where the syntax of both tool while exporting is totally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no such conversion tool** present anywhere. And I don't know much about flash tool **but yes, one hint** i can give to you is that Fabric.js has more than one way to export data; you can export data in object, json, svg, png etc.

If there is such things present in your flash tool than you can **export your image in SVG format** from flash and than you can load that image in Fabric.js.

I don't think it will have any problem.

Good luck.

Comment: in flash the data are stored with JSON, where as here the data can be load from json, but the json syntax and object position varies while loading on canvas.